# Missing Rows from Dataset in R

Tags: r

I have spent the better part of yesterday afternoon and this morning trying to gain some insight into my issue. If you can point me to any resources that would be great!

I have a dataframe in R (imported from an Oracle table), see the data below. I call it Loss_Data.

```
    Loss_Yr Dev_Lag Claim_Amnt
1   2007    1   300
2   2007    2   10
3   2007    3   250
4   2007    5   5
5   2008    1   450
6   2008    2   80
7   2008    4   3
8   2009    1   175
9   2009    3   20
10  2010    1   95
11  2010    2   40
12  2011    1   130
```

However, I need to get it to look like the following. I need to make sure that there is a row for every possible Loss_Yr and Dev_Lag combination. See the added rows

```
    Loss_Yr Dev_Lag Claim_Amnt
1   2007    1   300
2   2007    2   10
3   2007    3   250
***4    2007    4   0***
5   2007    5   5
6   2008    1   450
7   2008    2   80
***8    2008    3   0***
9   2008    4   3
10  2009    1   175
***11   2009    2   0***
12  2009    3   20
13  2010    1   95
14  2010    2   40
15  2011    1   130
```

At first I was thinking that I would create a "dummy" table with all possible combinations and then do a merge with my existing; keeping the records from my intial table, Loss_Data.

However, I am trying to build a process and this method wouldn't be very felxible.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?!

Comment: What about the method you outline wouldn't be flexible enough?

Comment: The other way I have done this in the past is essentially to cross-tabulate the data, filling in missing values as appropriate, and then un-tabulate it (`tapply` or `table` followed by `as.data.frame.table`, or something `plyr`-ish)

Comment: The reason I don't want to use the method with two tables is because I would have to keep creating a new table with possible combinations. To elaborate, not only will time pass which will require updates to the table of combos, but I may need to run by different increments of time. For example: by year, by quarter, by month, etc.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to write a loop that functioned like:
first_yr<-min(Loss_Yr)
last_yr<-max(Loss_Yr)
first_lag<-min(Dev_Lag)
final_lag<-max(Dev_Lag)

for(i in first_yr:last_yr) {
 for(j in first_lag:final_lag){
 check if record missing
 if missing create new with Loss_Yr & Dev_Lag and Claim_Amnt 0
 else use existing record
 next lag while (last_yr+1)-i-j>0 }
next Loss_Yr     }       The condition following while is not important. I want to know if this is possible since I lack experience with R. I have drawn out what I need to accomplish, but am having trouble getting there. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The approach you describe is the right idea. Maybe you're over-complicating the implementation?

```
d <- read.table(text="Loss_Yr Dev_Lag Claim_Amnt
1   2007    1   300
2   2007    2   10
3   2007    3   250
4   2007    5   5
5   2008    1   450
6   2008    2   80
7   2008    4   3
8   2009    1   175
9   2009    3   20
10  2010    1   95
11  2010    2   40
12  2011    1   130", header=TRUE, row.names=1)

filled <- merge(d, 
                with(d, expand.grid(Loss_Yr=unique(Loss_Yr), Dev_Lag=unique(Dev_Lag))), 
                all=TRUE)
```

Comment: and as the finishing touch,   d[ is.na( d ) ] <- 0 to replace those NAs with zeroes ;)