# How to create rows for missing data in my data frame

Tags: r, missing-data

I am modelling populations in different scenarios. Each scenario is repeated 1000 times and for 1000 years. The model output is a single table with three columns: repetition(R), year(Y), population size (N).
However, the model output does not contain data for years after the extinction event. For example if a population goes extinct (N=0) in year 600, I do not get any rows in my output table for the years 601 to 1000.

Here is a small example. Let's say I have three scenario repetitions, each modelled for 5 years. What I might get is:

```
R   Y   N
1   1   30
1   2   25
1   3   20
1   4   10
1   5   0
2   1   30
2   2   0
3   1   30
3   2   28
3   3   10
3   4   0

structure(list(R = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), Y = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), N = c(30L, 
25L, 20L, 10L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 28L, 10L, 0L)), .Names = c("R", 
"Y", "N"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

But what I need is:

```
R   Y   N
1   1   30
1   2   25
1   3   20
1   4   10
1   5   0
2   1   30
2   2   0
2   3   0
2   4   0
2   5   0
3   1   30
3   2   28
3   3   10
3   4   0
3   5   0
```

What is the fastest way to insert the missing rows?
Possibly using "apply" is a good idea?
Or maybe creating an empty data frame first

```
d <- data.frame(Rep=sort(rep(1:1000,1000)), Year=rep(1:1000,1000), NInds=numeric(1000000))
```

and then overwriting the values I have?

Comment: I just realized that this question was sufficiently answered before:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286582/missing-rows-from-dataset-in-r

Comment: than delete the question?

Comment: Even though similar questions existed before, within 10 minutes (!) better answers (faster code) showed up here. Great community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do something like that (although I'm not sure if your example is real or just toy and then it probably won't fit for your requirements).
Assuming that `dat` is your data

```
dat2 <- data.frame(R = rep(seq_len(3), each = 5), Y = rep(seq_len(5), 3), N = 0)
dat2$N[paste(dat2$R, dat2$Y) %in% paste(dat$R, dat$Y)] <- dat$N

#    R Y  N
# 1  1 1 30
# 2  1 2 25
# 3  1 3 20
# 4  1 4 10
# 5  1 5  0
# 6  2 1 30
# 7  2 2  0
# 8  2 3  0
# 9  2 4  0
# 10 2 5  0
# 11 3 1 30
# 12 3 2 28
# 13 3 3 10
# 14 3 4  0
# 15 3 5  0
```

Comment: pretty fast! thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, base-R only:

```
r2 <- rep(1:3, each=5)
y2 <- rep(1:5, times=3)
rymissing <- setdiff(paste(r2, y2), paste(df$R, df$Y))
rymissing <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(rymissing, " "))), ncol=2, dimnames=list(NULL, c("R", "Y")), byrow=TRUE)
df2 <- rbind(df, cbind(as.data.frame(rymissing), N=0))
df2 <- df2[order(df2$R, df2$Y),]
row.names(df2) <- NULL
df2
```

Comment: works fine too, but David Arenburgs code is faster (and shorter). Thank you very much anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(DF, .(R), function(df) {
  Y <- seq.int(max(DF$Y))
  N <- df$N
  length(N) <- length(Y)
  N[is.na(N)] <- 0
  data.frame(Y=Y, N=N)
})

#   R Y  N
#1  1 1 30
#2  1 2 25
#3  1 3 20
#4  1 4 10
#5  1 5  0
#6  2 1 30
#7  2 2  0
#8  2 3  0
#9  2 4  0
#10 2 5  0
#11 3 1 30
#12 3 2 28
#13 3 3 10
#14 3 4  0
#15 3 5  0
```

Obviously, if this is not fast enough, you could translate it to data.table or dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

`expand.grid` + `join` from `plyr` can help here:

```
data <- join(expand.grid(R=1:3, Y=1:5), data)
data$N[is.na(data$N)] <- 0

# not necessary but better for comparison to your example
data[order(data$R),]

# not necessary but better for comparison to your example
data[order(data$R),]
##    R Y  N
## 1  1 1 30
## 4  1 2 25
## 7  1 3 20
## 10 1 4 10
## 13 1 5  0
## 2  2 1 30
## 5  2 2  0
## 8  2 3  0
## 11 2 4  0
## 14 2 5  0
## 3  3 1 30
## 6  3 2 28
## 9  3 3 10
## 12 3 4  0
## 15 3 5  0
```

Interestingly enough, the "pure R" ones "win":

```
ddply
user  system elapsed 
0.003   0.000   0.003 

expand.grid
user  system elapsed 
0.002   0.000   0.002 

pureR
user  system elapsed 
0.001   0.000   0.001 

pureR2
user  system elapsed 
0.002   0.000   0.001
```

Comment: thanks for the speed comparison! Same results for me! "join" sounded promising, but is slightly slower.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution using base R only:

```
empty <- data.frame(R=sort(rep(1:3,5)), Y=rep(1:5,3), N=numeric(15))
res <- merge(empty,data,by=c("R","Y"),all=T)[,c(1,2,4)] 
res[is.na(res[,3]),3] <- 0 
names(res) <- c('R','Y','N')
```